# $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ vs $\bigcap\limits_\infty^{n = 1} A_n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

This is probably a trivial question, but what is the difference between those two?

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty = \{x \mid \forall  n \in \mathbb N, x \in A_n\}$$

What does the other intersection mean?

Comment: The notation on the right looks like a typo.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but it was written that way in two separate problems. So does the notation on the right have any meaning at all, or is it actually meaningless?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually we define merely
$$\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i=\{x\mid \forall i\in I\colon x\in A_i\}$$
where $I$ is some nonempty index set.
Alternate notations are common for two special cases:

(i) If $I=\{n, n+1, \ldots, m\}$, we write
$\bigcup_{i=n}^m A_i$ for $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$.

(ii) If $I=\{i\in\mathbb N\mid i\ge n\}$, we write $\bigcup_{i=n}^\infty A_i$ for $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$.

The notation you exhibit has never occured to me. It doesn't match notations for e.g. sums with $\Sigma$ either.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll assume that it was a typo until I can ask my professor about it tomorrow. That certainly makes the homework problem I am trying to do much easier.